# Given $f(z) = |z|^{z_1}$, what is $ f'{(z)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, frobenius-method, cauchy-riemann-equations

**Context**

I am working on the series solution of a second-order, homogeneous, linear, ordinary differential equation. Irrespective of the two roots of the indical equation, one of the two linearly independent solutions has the form
$$
|z|^{z_1}\left(1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\,z^n\right).
$$
I will need to differentiate this solution to plug it into the governing differential equation. Thus, I need to answer the following question.

**Question**

Given $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $z_1\in \mathbb{C}$, and $f(z) = |z|^{z_1}$, if $f'{(z)}$ exists, what is $f'{(z)}$?

**Solution**

In this solution, I use the following nation:
$$ z = x+ i\,y\qquad\text{and}\qquad z_1 = x_1+ i\,y_1.$$
Additionally, from the fact that
\begin{align*}
f(z) 
&= |z|^{z_1}
\\
&= |x+ i\,y|^{x_1+ i\,y_1}
\\
&= \left[\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}\right]^{x_1+ i\,y_1}
\\
&= \left[\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}\right]^{x_1 }\,\left[\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}\right]^{ i\,y_1}
\\
&= \left[\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}\right]^{x_1 }\,\left[e^{\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}}\right]^{ i\,y_1}
\\
&= \left[\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}\right]^{x_1 }\,\left[e^{ i\,y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}}\right] 
\\
&= 
\left[\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}\right]^{x_1 }\,\left[
\cos{  \left(y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}\right) }
+i\,
\sin{ \left(  y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}} \right)}
\right] 
\\
&= 
\cos{  \left(y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}\right) }\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2} }
+
i\,
\sin{ \left(  y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}} \right)}
\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2} }  
\end{align*}
I write the real and imaginary parts of $f$, respectively, as
\begin{align*}
u(x,y)
&=
\cos{  \left(y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}\right) }\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2} },
\\
v(x,y)
&=
\sin{ \left(  y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}} \right)}
\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2} }  
.
\end{align*}

I know that if, and only if, the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied that the derivative exists.

*First Cauchy-Riemann condition*

I need to check if
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
&=
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.
\end{align*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
&=
\frac{\partial \cos{  \left(y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}\right) }\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2} }}{\partial x}
\\
&=
- y_1\,\frac{\frac{2\,x}{2\,\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}   }{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}   \sin{  \left(y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}\right) }\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2} } 
+
 \cos{  \left(y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}\right) }\frac{x_1\,2\,x}{2}\,\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2}-1 } 
\\
&=
x\left[
- y_1\,      \sin{  \left(y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}\right) }
+
x_1\, \cos{  \left(y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}\right) }  \right]
\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2}-1 } .
\end{align*}
Further,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
&=
\frac{\partial \sin{ \left(  y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}} \right)}
\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2} }}{\partial y}
\\
&=
y_1\,\frac{\frac{2\,y}{2\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}}{  \sqrt{x^2+  y^2}}  \cos{ \left(  y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}} \right)}
\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2} } 
+
\frac{2\,y\,x_1}{2}  \sin{ \left(  y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}} \right)}
\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2}-1 } 
\\
&=
y\left[ y_1\,  \cos{ \left(  y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}} \right)}
+
x_1\,  \sin{ \left(  y_1\,\log{\sqrt{x^2+  y^2}} \right)}
\right]\left[ x^2+  y^2 \right]^{\frac{x_1}{2}-1 } 
\end{align*}

I have found that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
\neq
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.
\end{align*}

My conclusion is that given $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $z_1\in \mathbb{C}$, and $f(z) = |z|^{z_1}$, $f'{(z)}$ does not exist. Yet, I have doubts and seek alternative solutions from the community.

Comment: $|z|^a$ is not analytic (on any domain) for any $a \ne 0$ so there is no $f'$ in the complex sense